# Validating non-model select box CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In the following from a have a select box which is not related to any database fields:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Event');

    echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', array('label' => __('Customer')));
    echo $this->Form->input('service_id', array('label'=>__('Service'))); 
    echo $this->Form->select('user_id', $users, array('multiple'=>true));

echo $this->Form->end(__('Save'));
```

In the Event model I have a validation rule which is as follows:

```
var $validate = array(

    'user_id'=>array(
        'notempty'=> array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=> 'Vælg en medarbejder'
        )
    ))
```

THe problem is that this validation rule is never called. What may the problem be?

Here is the dump of data after from submition:

```
array(
    'customer_id' => '107',
    'service_id' => '195',
    'user_id' => '',
    ...
)
```

The rule has just been tested on edit and it works perfectly, together with the remaining rules. The problem is that none of the rules are fired on create.

Comment: As I can see you are trying to validate select, is the data really empty? Can you show dumpof `$this->request->data`?

Comment: Just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validates manually. Try this in your Controller.

```
$this->Event->set($this->request->data);
if ($this->Event->validates()) {
        //Save your data by calling $this->Event->save($this->request->data);
} else {
// didn’t validate logic
$errors = $this->ModelName->validationErrors;
}
```

Comment: Well this is always an option, but is there no possible way to validate it properly?

Comment: Your validation will called just before saving data. Thus your 'user_id' is not going to save, its not gona validate as i understand.

Comment: The validation rule works perfectly well on edit, but just not on create. Maybe that is going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Validation doesn't apply on select(), hidden(), radio() etc. You should always go through Form::input() like:

```
$this->Form->input(
   'user_id', 
   array(
      'type'=>'select', 
      'options'=>$users, 
      'multiple'=>true, ....));
```

Then the validation will be called as expected ;)

Comment: But this way it becomes a dropdown where only one value can be selected instead of multiple.

Comment: input supports multiple just add it next to type, options etc

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I did follow the exaple, but the validation is still not being applied.

Comment: The validation rule works perfectly well on edit, but just not on create. Maybe that is going to help.